# Ignore empty textbox

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I'm making update info page for users with dreamweaver, but when I try to update other fields like (username) and I don't touch the "password textbox" it still changes on database to NULL password... (empty) How can I fix this? So if the password textbox is empty, it should ignore it and not write the new password on database.

```
    $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "login")) {
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE users SET Username=%s, Password=%s WHERE Email=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Username'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Password'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Email'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());

$updateGoTo = "profile.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not at all that familiar with using `sprintf` and `GetSQLValueString`, so my solution in this case would be to check for all `$_POST`-values and have separate update-queries, like so

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "login")) {
    mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

    if (!empty($_POST['Username'])) {
        $updateSQLuser = sprintf("UPDATE users SET Username=%s", GetSQLValueString($_POST['Username'], "text"));
        $ResultUser = mysql_query($ResultUser, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['Password'])) {
        $updateSQLuser = sprintf("UPDATE users SET Password=%s", GetSQLValueString($_POST['Password'], "text"));
        $ResultPass = mysql_query($ResultPass, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    if (!empty($_POST['Email'])) {
        $updateSQLuser = sprintf("UPDATE users SET Email=%s", GetSQLValueString($_POST['Email'], "text"));
        $ResultEmail = mysql_query($ResultEmail, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Is this a solution that could work for you?

Also, usage of `mysql_*` is depcicated and no longer officially maintained - you'd be strongly advised to switch to `mysqli_*`or `PDO`.

Comment: Thank you for your replay , i will try to migrate mysql_ to pod . This is generated with Adobe Dramweaver that's why im using this method now . i will try the suggested solution and i will repaly here again . thank you

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: ResultUser Line 118 .
Query was empty
$ResultUser = mysql_query($ResultUser, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());